# How to use Laravel pagination with Sphinx

Tags: php, laravel, sphinx

In my search controller I use Sphinx for fetching the results. It looks like this:

```
    $cl = new SphinxSearch();

    $results = $cl->setMatchMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
    $results = $cl->setSortMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC, "start");
    $results = $cl->search('@*' . $name, 'spots');
    $results = $cl->get();
```

It shows me a couple of hundred results and it is really heavy to load. I know that the Laravel has feature for pagination (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination), but I don't know how to use it with this Sphinx package. BTW I use this one - https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create paginator using Sphinx results. After getting paginated results from Sphinx.

```
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $results,
        $totalResultsCount,
        $perPage,
        $currentPage
    );
    $paginator->setCollection(collect($results));
```

Comment: I get this `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator::setCollection() must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection, array given, `

Comment: Make collection, so pass collect($results)

Comment: It works great. How can I render this `$paginator` in blade?

Answer (score 0):

When manually creating a paginator instance, you should manually "slice" the array of results you pass to the paginator. So a method from a controller would look like this:

```
public function doSearch()
{
    $template = 'search/search_results';
    $filters = Input::get('filter');
    $currentPage = Input::get('page') ? Input::get('page') : 1;
    $perPage = 5;
    // prepare $sphinxQuery using the filters received
    $results = SphinxSearch::search($sphinxQuery, 'indexname')
        ->setFieldWeights(
            array(
                    'name' => 10,
            )
        )
        ->setMatchMode(SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED)
        ->setSortMode(SphinxClient::SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "name ASC")
        ->limit(1000)
        ->get(true);
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
        collect($results)->forPage($currentPage, $perPage), sizeof($results), $perPage, $currentPage
    );
    $paginator->setPath(route('name.of.the.route'));
    $paginator->setPageName('page');  
    $data['items'] = $paginator;  

    return View::make($template, $data);
}
```

And in the blade template:

```
<?php echo $items->appends(['filter' => Request::get('filter')])->render(); ?>
```